# How to use Counter variable in reporting of Salesforce Lightning version

Tags: lightning-aura-components, reporting, lightning-apps, salesfoce

I have requirement to show the counter variable in Salesforce reporting.

This counter variable is nothing but no. of times the user clicks on the hyperlink. So for these i have already created the counter with below logic and i just want to know how can i used this variable in my reporting for Lightning version.

```
<aura:attribute name="counter1" default="0" type="integer"/>
    
    <lightning:button variant="Test1" label="Click" onclick="{!c.handleClick }" />
 Counter value is : {!v.counter1}
```

---

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set('v.counter1',component.get('v.counter1')+1);
        
    }
})
```

Please let me know how i can used this variable for reporting in Lightning.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how many times all users clicked the link?

Comment: Yes i need to capture these count in the report.